# C++ passing 2d array by reference to other class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, reference

Idea is that MapGrid creates ands holds 2d array with map elements and I want to give that array to another class MapGenerator so it generates a real map by editing square elements in it.

```
class MapGenerator {
        private:
            int MAP_HEIGHT;
            int MAP_WIDTH;
            Square * worldMap;
            void cmdGenerateHeightMap() {
             worldMap[i][j]->decraseHeight();
              ......
            }
        public:
        MapGenerator(Square &myMap, int maxHeight, maxWidth) {
                MAP_WIDTH = maxWidth
                MAP_HEIGHT = maxHeight;
                worldMap = &myMap;
                cmdGenerateHeightMap();
        }
    }    
class MapGrid {
        private:
            static const int MAP_HEIGHT = 100;
            static const int MAP_WIDTH = 100;
            Square worldMap[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH];
        public:
            MapGrid() {
              for (int i=0; i<MAP_HEIGHT;i++) {
                for (int j=0;j<MAP_WIDTH; j++) {
                    worldMap[i][j] = Square();
                }
              }
              MapGenerator myMap(worldMap); 
            }
            void PrintMyMap() {
            //print what the map MapGenerator made
            }
    }
```

I get this error: variable ‘MapGenerator myMap’ has initializer but incomplete type map.h
Could I get some more human sounding hints what is wrong

Comment: What does the "MapGenerator myMap(worldMap); " doing in method MapGrid thats giving problem.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the order in which the `MapGenerator` and `MapGrid` classes are defined. You're trying to use the `MapGenerator` class inside the `MapGrid` constructor, but that class is only defined further below.

**UPDATE**: Okay, now that you rewrote your question, here's another guess (your code doesn't actually compile, so I can only guess): is it possible that `MapGenerator` and `MapGrid` are in different header files and in the header file of `MapGrid` you only have a forward declaration of `MapGenerator` instead of the actual definition (which you would get by including `MapGenerator`'s header)?

Comment: did that, real problem is that i am passing array wrongly i think

Comment: yea, both classes are in different files. main.cpp has include header.h and in header.h there is forward declaration for both classes and #include to each classes header file. MapGeneration foward declare and #include comes before MapGrid

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you want to be passing `worldMap` in the MapGrid constructor method when it hasn't been initialized to anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

In order to instantiate an object for a class, you need the full information of the class. But in the class `MapGrid`, trying to instantiate an object for `MapGenerator` is invalid in the current form of code snippet ordering. Instead, try this -

```
class MapGenerator
{
    // .....
};

class MapGrid
{
    // ....
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is similar to yours just after commenting the error prone line. Can you tell me what was its utility?.

```
class MapGenerator {
    private:
        Square * worldMap;
        void cmdGenerateHeightMap() {
        //do something to the orginal copy of worldMap
        }
    public:
    MapGenerator(Square &myMap) {
            worldMap = &myMap;
            cmdGenerateHeightMap();
    }
};

class MapGrid {
    private:
        static const int MAP_HEIGHT = 100;
        static const int MAP_WIDTH = 100;
        Square worldMap[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH];
    public:
        MapGrid() {
          for (int i=0; i<MAP_HEIGHT;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<MAP_WIDTH; j++) {
                worldMap[i][j] = Square();
            }
          }
          //commented following line
          //MapGenerator myMap(worldMap);
        }
        void PrintMyMap() {
        //print what the map MapGenerator made
        }


};
```

Comment: well idea is i MapGid makes default map. flat with no rivers nothing(Square holds that info). MapGenerator takes the default map and adds mountines rivers and other kinda stuff. Then it gives the map back to MapGrid to be used in game.

Answer (score 0):

I think `MapGenerator` doesn't need to be a class.
Probably `cmdGenerateHeightMap` can be a free standing function, instead of
a member function.
Alternatively, in order to simplify the access to two dimensional array,
I'd suggest making a dedicated class, for example `TwoDimArray`.
How about calling `cmdGenerateHeightMap` from `MapGrid`'s constructor like the
following?:

```
struct TwoDimArray {
  int  MAP_WIDTH;
  Square  *worldMap;
  TwoDimArray( Square* m, int w ) : worldMap( m ), MAP_WIDTH( w ) {}
  Square* operator[]( int i ) const { return worldMap + MAP_WIDTH * i; }
};

void cmdGenerateHeightMap( Square *myMap, int maxHeight, int maxWidth )
{
  TwoDimArray  worldMap( myMap, maxWidth );
  ...
  worldMap[i][j].decraseHeight();
  ...
}

class MapGrid {
  ...
  MapGrid() {
    ...
    cmdGenerateHeightMap( worldMap[0], MAP_HEIGHT, MAP_WIDTH );
  }
};
```

Hope this helps